# How to add files to external drive on raspberry pi via owncloud after server installation

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, raspberry-pi, owncloud

I installed apache, php and owncloud on my raspberry pi via this guide: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Owncloud-dropbox-clone/?ALLSTEPS

I got all the way to $ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/owncloud (replaced with /media/USBxxx referring to my connected usb flash drive) and included the same drive in the Owncloud setup screen for data location.

Now that everything seems to be set up, when I upload a file to Owncloud, it is not writing to the USB drive. There is no error message, I just do not see the files I upload via the Owncloud web interface. When I hover one of the files in the interface, the file location states: https://192.168.x.xxx/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/ajax/download.php?dir=%2Fdocuments&files=filename.txt

And on a related note, when I type in the local ip of my web server hosted on my pi, I get the message that it works but no content has been added yet.

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Comment: Added the info to the post

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the config.php file.

Usually you can find it in /var/www/[YOUR OWNCLOUD DIRECTORY]/config.

Set the *datadirectory* to your mountpoint mount your device and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your external hard drive is mounted with the necessary permissions.  You may have forgotten to use `sudo chmod 755 /media/owncloud` or `sudo chmod 777 /media/owncloud` (for more security). Doing this will allow your Raspberry Pi to write to the hdd.

Sources:

The same link you used and my own owncloud server (that I also set up on a Raspberry Pi).